# Knockout: nest input element in label tag with data-bind properties

Tags: html, knockout.js, data-binding, label

I want to use the `label` tag without mapping the `for` attribute to the `input`'s `id` as described by [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1). Like:

```
<label>
    <input type="...">
</label>
```

Now I try to get it work with **knockout**.

My Model:

```
function myViewModel(data) {
    this.Name = "Max";
    this.Value = "1337";
}
```

My first approach was:

```
<label data-bind="text: Name">
    <input data-bind="value: Value" />
</label>
```

**But** of course the `label` 's data binding overwrites its content. So no `input` will show up.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f49c32zx/

**Question:** How can I get this work?

I didn't tried putting the whole `input` element with all attributes and values as value of a property of my model - that doesn't give me a good feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a span or virtual tag inside the label tag, and put the text binding on that interior tag.

```
<label>
    <!-- ko text: Name --><!-- /ko -->
    <input data-bind="value: Value" />
</label>
```

Comment: Here seems to be the explanation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html This was new for me! Thank you for the quick solution with explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
<label> <!-- ko text: Name --><!-- /ko -->
    <input data-bind="value: Value" />
</label>
```